# Leveling wood floor for laminate wood floor

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

I am laying down some laminate wood floor this week in my house over some older wood plank flooring. I was just going to put roofing paper down and then some foam style underlayment Home Depot recommended. The issue is the floor, being old planks, is not very level spanning the room. The corners are pretty low, maybe 1/4" dip. Should I lay down some liquid floor leveler on this floor or just build up the underlayment to make it more level?

Thanks.

[image: Old Floor]

Comment: What direction will the new floor run?  Parallel or perpendicular to the subfloor boards?

Comment: @JPhi1618 it would run the opposite direction, or perpendicular, to the current floor.

Comment: Is that a 1/4" dip over the last 2 feet, 4 feet, etc?  Unless it's a pretty severe drop at the end, shouldn't be an issue, but a more seasoned floor installer might have a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Those planks look really cupped and separated. Floor leveler probably isn't a good choice; too many ways for it to go through the floor. It needs a overlay with plywood to make for a solid smooth base. Just ensure that the plywood is laminated and properly fastened to the subfloor. The thinner the plywood the flatter the subfloor needs to be, that means sanding and filling the cups in the wood before laminating to it. From there you can level it off easily.